# How to print a value from a file with comments printed?

Tags: batch-file

In a program am getting one input say name....

From a file i read value line by line:
say file contains...

```
hello
hai
```

If i want to print like

```
hello name in batch file
hai name in batch file
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following (pure `cmd`) script will do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (infile.txt) do (
    echo %%a name in batch file
)
endlocal
```

For the input file (`infile.txt`):

```
    hello
    hai
```

it produces:

```
hello name in batch file
hai name in batch file
```

I gather you'd need to adjust the "name in batch file" bit of the script to be something more suitable (like `"Bob"` for example).

---

*Update:*

Provided you have correctly created the `name` variable before entering the `for` loop, you can also use variables for the name. For example, the following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /p name=Enter name:
for /f %%a in (infile.txt) do (
    echo %%a !name!
)
endlocal
```

allows:

```
c:\pax> .\go.cmd
Enter name: Pax
hello Pax
hai Pax
```

c:\pax> _

Comment: You need to ensure that name is defined, as in 'set name=Bob' before the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows command line use

```
ECHO %1
```

Comment: for %%a in wish.txt Do type %%a prints only hello 
hai

how to incorporate type and echo in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about a Perl Solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $file = "file.txt";
open(INFO,"<$file") or die "can't open file" ;

while(<INFO>)
{
  chomp $_;
  print "$_ name in batch file\n" ;
}
```